# Add multiple` plotly.express.bar` figures into one window

Tags: python, plotly

I have 3 bar charts with separated data-frames and x,y labels. I can not use make_subplot tool since it is compatible with graph_object instance, not with express.bar. In this case, I've read documentations about facet_row(facet_col) properties which plots bars in one figure but it does not fit to my case. I literally want 3 different figures in one page/window.
I create bar charts as below:

```
import plotly.express as px

x = ['one', 'two', 'three']
y = [1, 2, 3]    

dataframe1 = {
    "x_axis_1": x,
    "y_axis_1": y
}

fig1 = px.bar(dataframe1, x="x_axis_1", y="y_axis_1")
fig1.update_xaxes(type='category')
```

Thank you for any idea in advance!

Comment: Do you want 3 different bar charts in one plotly figure? Or is it 3 different plots one after the another? In the second case its simply creating fig2 and fig3 like you have done and using dataframe2 and dataframe3 and using fig2.show() and fig3.show()

Comment: Yes, exactly as you mentioned but I don't call show() because I want to show all of them in one page, not one window per figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned the `add_traces` expects us to input instances of trace classes from the `plotly.graph_objects` package (e.g `plotly.graph_objects.Scatter, plotly.graph_objects.Bar`) (see [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_traces))

However since you do not want to use graph_objects we have to find a workaround

Each `fig` that you create using plotly express has 2 parts : data and layout

For example for your bar chart, if I do:

```
print (fig1)
>>>
Figure({
    'data': [{'alignmentgroup': 'True',
              'hovertemplate': 'x_axis_1=%{x}<br>y_axis_1=%{y}<extra></extra>',
              'legendgroup': '',
              'marker': {'color': '#636efa'},
              'name': '',
              'offsetgroup': '',
              'orientation': 'v',
              'showlegend': False,
              'textposition': 'auto',
              'type': 'bar',
              'x': array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object),
              'xaxis': 'x',
              'y': array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64),
              'yaxis': 'y'}],
    'layout': {'barmode': 'relative',
               'legend': {'tracegroupgap': 0},
               'margin': {'t': 60},
               'template': '...',
               'xaxis': {'anchor': 'y', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'x_axis_1'}},
               'yaxis': {'anchor': 'x', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'y_axis_1'}}}
})
```

If we check the data parameter its a list of plotly graph_object classes:

```
print (fig1['data'][0])
>>>
Bar({
    'alignmentgroup': 'True',
    'hovertemplate': 'x_axis_1=%{x}<br>y_axis_1=%{y}<extra></extra>',
    'legendgroup': '',
    'marker': {'color': '#636efa'},
    'name': '',
    'offsetgroup': '',
    'orientation': 'v',
    'showlegend': False,
    'textposition': 'auto',
    'x': array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object),
    'xaxis': 'x',
    'y': array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64),
    'yaxis': 'y'
})
print(type(fig1['data'][0]))
>>>
<class 'plotly.graph_objs._bar.Bar'>
```

So basically we have to extract this out from the plotly express figure and pass it to `add_traces` for it to work

**The complete solution**

Generate some data:

```
x1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
y1 = [1, 2, 3] 

x2 = ['five', 'six', 'seven']
y2 = [5, 6, 7] 

x3 = ['eight', 'nine', 'ten']
y3 = [8, 9, 10] 

dataframe1 = {
    "x_axis_1": x,
    "y_axis_1": y
}

dataframe2 = {
    "x_axis_2": x2,
    "y_axis_2": y2
}

dataframe3 = {
    "x_axis_3": x3,
    "y_axis_3": y3
}
```

Generate the plot:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)
fig1 = px.bar(dataframe1, x="x_axis_1", y="y_axis_1")
fig2 = px.bar(dataframe2, x="x_axis_2", y="y_axis_2")
fig3 = px.bar(dataframe3, x="x_axis_3", y="y_axis_3")


fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][0], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][0], row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig3['data'][0], row=3, col=1)

fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see by querying the `data` key from the plotly express figure, we get the required format we need to pass to the `add_traces` method.

Comment: Sincere thanks to you. Would you please tell me your plotly version? graph_object.Bar figures show blank bars and it's just bug of the library itself.

Comment: Gald to help! I'm using Plotly version '4.12.0'